# calculus of vatiations; finding the minimum value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the minimum value of the quadratic form:

$$x^{2}+2y^{2}+3z^{2}+2xy+2xz$$

subject to the condition:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the method of [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).
Introduce the function
$$\Lambda(x,y,z,\lambda)=x^{2}+2y^{2}+3z^{2}+2xy+2xz +\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-1) $$

And try to solve the system $\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda}\Lambda=0$:

$$
\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial x}=(1+\lambda)x+y+z=0\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial y}=x+(2+\lambda)y=0\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial z}=x+(3+\lambda) z=0\\
\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial \lambda}=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$$

The last equation is just the original constraint (the points $(x,y,z)$ have to lie on the unit sphere).